# PHP Shuffle Multiple Decks

Tags: php, shuffle, blackjack

I have the following PHP code which shuffles 1 deck; however - I'm looking to shuffle 6 decks like a casino would do in a game of Blackjack. Any thoughts on how to achieve this?

```
    private $suites = array('c', 'd', 'h', 's');
    private $ranks = array('2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 't', 'j', 'q', 'k', 'a');
    private $deck = array();


    for ($i = 0; $i < count($this->deck); $i++) {
            $r = $i + rand(0, 51 - $i);
            $temp = $this->deck[$i];
            $this->deck[$i] = $this->deck[$r];
            $this->deck[$r] = $temp;
        }
```

Comment: what's the desired output?

Comment: have you heard about PHP's [`shuffle()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php)?

Comment: Shuffle function? http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php

Comment: My desired output is an array of individual cards, like below -  But I want it to be 6 decks deep.  Array ( [0] => jh [1] => 9c [2] => 5d [3] => qd [4] => td [5] => 3h [6] => 8d [7] => 6d [8] => ac [9] => 6c [10] => tc [11] => 9h [12] => 6h [13] => ts [14] => .....

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$decks = array_merge($deck1, $deck2, ...);
shuffle($decks);
```

Comment: I think this is close to what I'm looking for - but I can't seem to apply that concept to my code. Can you elaborate with my example?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.

```
CONST COUNT_DECKS = 6;

$suites = array('c', 'd', 'h', 's');
$ranks = array('2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 't', 'j', 'q', 'k', 'a');

$deck = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < COUNT_DECKS; $i++)
    foreach ($ranks as $rank)
        foreach ($suites as $suit)
            $deck[] = $suit . $rank;

shuffle($deck);
var_dump($deck);
```

Answer (score 0):

So I basically solved this using the following method (first I loaded up $deck1 with all the 52 cards, in order.

```
    for($i =0;$i<6;$i++){
            $decks = array_merge($decks,$deck1);
        }

        shuffle($decks);
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($this->deck); $i++) {
            $this->deck[$i] = $decks[$i];
        }
```